# create a primary key for a one-to-one relationship

Tags: typeorm, nest

Background:

Since any unique entity data is a candidate key to a table, any data column constrained as `unique` is a candidate key. What is the syntax for a foreign key to be constrained as unique and a primary key. E.g. I have entities:

```
@Entity()
export class A extends BaseEntity {
  PrimaryColumn()
  id: number;
}  
  
@Entity()
export class B extends BaseEntity() {
  @OneToOne(() => A) <---- need to set this foreign key unique and the primary key of B
  @JoinColumn()
  a: A;
}
```

As marked above, I'd like the foreign key to be unique and the primary key of B.

What I've tried so far:

I thought I had found the solution, but this syntax seems outdated; the `RelationOptions` does not contain the `primary` property:

```
@OneToOne( type => A, {primary: true})
@JoinColumn()
a: A
```

Also, it does seem possible to mark a column as [unique using the @Unique](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/decorator-reference#unique)  decorator, but, would like to know if there's a better approach to making the column unique in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Watch out for changes here:** [Typeorm changelogs](https://typeorm.io/changelog)

primary relation (e.g. @ManyToOne(() => User, { primary: true }) user: User) support is removed. You still have an ability to use foreign keys as your primary keys, however now you must explicitly define a column marked as primary.

Example, before:

```
@ManyToOne(() => User, { primary: true })
user: User
```

Now:

```
@PrimaryColumn()
userId: number

@ManyToOne(() => User)
user: User
```

**Primary column name must match the relation name + join column name on related entity.** If related entity has multiple primary keys, and you want to point to multiple primary keys, you can define multiple primary columns the same way:

```
@PrimaryColumn()
userFirstName: string

@PrimaryColumn()
userLastName: string

@ManyToOne(() => User)
user: User
```

Comment: This particular statement seems to be important: `Primary column name must match the relation name + join column name on related entity. `

Comment: it also seem to be possible to rename the relationship column using the `@JoinColumn({name: 'newName'})`